# Send Multiple forms (edit multiple objects) in one Submit button (Ruby)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have numerous objects (customers) populating a table and I need to edit a particular field for each row/customer (via radio buttons) and save all via a single submit button at the bottom of the table.

I figure it would be best to render a form for each line ("accept_reject_form") in which I have my two radio buttons but I can't figure out how to have the form so on submission each selection is saved for each of the customers.

I've spent a while looking at a few similar questions, but none quite address this problem. Any help would be much appreciated :-)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Available Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= customer.name %></th>
        <th><%= customer.age %></th>  
        <th><%= render 'accept_reject_form' %></th>
      </tr>
    <% end %>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your `accept_reject_form` patial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a form per line: each form generates a request, this is hugely inefficient.  Instead, the data submitted by the form needs to be structured in such a way that your controller action can update multiple records just by looking at the contents of params.

I would make sure that, in the `accept_reject_form` partial, you **don't** have the form tag and just have the fields.  The form tag should be wrapped around the block where you iterate over @customer: in this case it will need to go around the whole table.

Give each field in your form partial a name value like

```
"customers[#{customer.id}][first_name]"
"customers[#{customer.id}][last_name]"
```

etc

This will then come through to the controller like

```
params = {:customers => {123 => {:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Smith"}, 456 => {:first_name => "Susan", :last_name => "Thompson"}}
```

Then in the controller (eg the update action) you can do something like this:

```
if params[:customer] && params[:id]
  #traditional params structure for updating a single record
  @customer = Customer.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
elsif params[:customers] #note plural
  #new params structure for updating multiple records
  @customers = []
  params[:customers].each do |id, attrs|
    customer = Customer.find_by_id(id)
    customer.update_attributes(attrs)
    @customers << customer
  end
end
```

this could use some error checking but you get the idea, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with your help. This approach was way more efficient! :-)